# Postgresql 12 streaming replication: restored replica but still not working

Tags: postgresql

Primary and salve server started showing a "requested WAL segment has already been removed" error after I've changed the PostgreSQL configs.
So, I decided to restore the backup from the primary server using the following steps:

- Shut down the replica server.
- Removed PostgreSQL data directory on the replica (`/var/lib/postgresql/12/main`)
- Performed the base backup (`sudo -u postgres pg_basebackup -h [PRIMARY_IP] -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/main -U replication -P -v -R`) and completed successfully.
- Started replica again.

But the error mentioned above still showing.

Configs on primary and slave:

```
wal_level = 'replica'
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'cd .'
max_wal_senders = 48
wal_keep_segments = 50
hot_standby = on
```

When I run `pg_basebackup ..` command, I got this logs:

```
pg_basebackup: checkpoint completed
pg_basebackup: write-ahead log start point: 188/92000148 on timeline 1
pg_basebackup: starting background WAL receiver
```

I'm curious why it says from 188, not 0.

Answer (score 2):

You need a replication slot to keep the primary from removing WAL that is still needed by the standby.

- Create the replication slot with `pg_create_logical_replication_slot` on the primary.
- Use the replication slot with the `-S` option of `pg_basebackup`.
- Make sure `primary_slot_name` is set in the standby configuration. `pg_basebackup`'s `-R` option will do that automatically.

Comment: I'll check try solution and let you know about the result. Thanks!